# Do external web cams work with MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I don't like using the built-in iSight camera as I want to adjust the angle etc.  Do external web cams still work with MacBooks with built-in camers?

I have a MacBook Pro 13" with Snow Leopard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most external webcams will work fine with a MacBook Pro with a built-in camera.  Just check the box for the camera before you purchase to ensure it's compatible.  Some webcams may come with bundled software which only works on Windows which is why you should check before you buy in case the software features are important to you.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to your answer is to check the various programs on the Mac to make sure they automatically or manually will switch between the built in iSight and the external camera connected through USB. The new beta of Messages has a checkbox in the video pref pane that when checked will open it when an external video camera is turned on. Other software like Skype may have prefs that control which camera is used and when.

Comment: Good point, Richard. Feel free to amend my answer. Thanks